# How to extend a BLoC in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I'm relatively new to dart and flutter. I would like to create a base bloc that can be extended by another to inherit and/or override events defined in the base bloc as well as provide its own. Having one bloc extend another seems fine until I attempt to use the extended bloc with BlocBuilder. In my example, the base bloc is called `BlocABloc` and the sub bloc is called `BlocBBloc`.

I get an error which says:

> 'BlocBBloc' doesn't conform to the bound 'StateStreamable' of the type parameter 'B'.
> Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'StateStreamable'

If extending a bloc isn't prohibited, what might I be missing which causes this to not work? Thanks. My sources are below.

**Block A Source**

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class BlocABloc extends Bloc<BlocAEvent, BlocAState> {
  BlocABloc(BlocAInitial blocAInitial) : super(const BlocAInitial(count: 0)) {
    on<Increment>((event, emit) {
      emit(BlocAState(count: state.count + 1));
    });
  }
}

class BlocAState extends Equatable {
  const BlocAState({required this.count});
  final int count;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [count];
}

final class BlocAInitial extends BlocAState {
  const BlocAInitial({required super.count});
}

class BlocAEvent extends Equatable {
  const BlocAEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class Increment extends BlocAEvent {}
```

**Bloc B Source**

```
import '../bloc_a/bloc_a_bloc.dart';

class BlocBBloc extends BlocABloc {
  BlocBBloc() : super(const BlocAInitial(count: 0)) {
    on<BlocBEvent>((event, emit) {
      // TODO: implement event handler
    });
  }
}

sealed class BlocBState extends BlocAState {
  const BlocBState({required super.count});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class BlocBInitial extends BlocBState {
  const BlocBInitial({required super.count});
}

sealed class BlocBEvent extends BlocAEvent {
  const BlocBEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

**Main**

```
import 'package:bloc_extended/bloc_a/bloc_a_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'bloc_b/bloc_b_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const _Home(key: Key('home')),
    );
  }
}

class _Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('BLoC')),
      body: BlocProvider<BlocBBloc>(
        create: (_) => BlocBBloc(),
        child: BlocBuilder<BlocBBloc, BlocBState>(  ///<------ ERROR HERE
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Center(child: Text('${state.count}')),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<BlocBBloc>().add(Increment());
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this error occur because of trying to use BlocBState. as BlocBBloc extends BlocABloc then it should use states from BlocABloc. and states from BlocABloc know nothing about BlocBState. what you can do it is something like this:

```
abstract class BlocAState<T> extends Equatable {...}

abstract class BlocABloc<Event, T> extends Bloc<Event, BlocAState<T> {..}
```

then you could extend this bloc like this:

```
sealed class BlocBState extends Equatable {..}

class BlocBBloc extends BlocABloc<BlocBEvent, BlocBState>{..}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you provide a full example using the code I provided? I tried what you suggested but more errors are generated with the constructors and event handlers. Thanks again.

Comment: Using the extends keyword twice here is not allowed in dart `class BlocBBloc extends BlocABloc extends BlocABloc<BlocBEvent, BlocBState>{..}`.

Comment: it was just typo

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested but it still throws the same error when I try to use BlockBuilder<BlocBBloc, BlocBState>. Can you provide a working example? Thanks.